# Displaying objects returned by controller in view in C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm a beginner in C# MVC, but I'm working on some project.

I've searched through Internet and found no solution matching my question. None of the answears solved my problem. The problem is: how to loop through every project (as you will see in code fragments below) and display them in view.

Project model code:

```
 public class AddProjectViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Project name length is too long. Maximum lenght is 50 char.")]
        public string ProjectName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Description length is too long. Maximum lenght is 50 char.")]
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

Project controller code:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var loggedUser = _workContext.GetUserId();

        var userProjects = _userProjectsRepository.GetAllEntity().Where(x => x.UserId == loggedUser);

        var model = new Models.ProjectViewModels.ShowUserProjectsViewModel();

        model.Projects = userProjects;

        return View(model);
    }
```

The idea is: when the page loads up, display every project that logged user can see.

I've tried something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
@model IEnumerable<CarPooling.Website.Models.ProjectViewModels>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div>
        <p>@Html.DisplayFor(m=>item)</p>
    </div>
}
```

Please, be patient with me and thanks for every response.

Comment: Why doesn't it work? What do you expect should happen, what is actually happening, and how are the two different?

Comment: The error that breaks the app was saying that the type of model item passed into the dictionary is not IEnumerable. But when I deleted the IEnumerable from my model in view, it breaks on foreach saying that "CS1579: foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'CarPooling.Website.Models.ProjectViewModels' because 'CarPooling.Website.Models.ProjectViewModels' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'"

Comment: _"but it doesn't work"_ is not a suitable explanation. You have multiple errors and you need to include the exception details in the question. And the first exception your getting is because the model you pass to the view is a single instance of `ShowUserProjectsViewModel` yet your view expects a model with is a collection of `ProjectViewModels`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller you are passing to your View a `ShowUserProjectsViewModel` object, but then you declare your model as `IEnumerable<CarPooling.Website.Models.ProjectViewModels>` inside your .cshtml View.

Use the same model type you passed inside your controller, and also remember to use the same properties defined in your ViewModel classes, as shown below:

```
@model ShowUserProjectsViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@foreach (var item in Model.Projects)
{
    <div>
        <p>@Html.DisplayFor(m=>item.ProjectName)</p>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: That's what I was missing. Thank you very much!